# Adding colour to text from a array of colours

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to add different colours to different texts. The list of colours that I would like to add is stored in an array. How will I use that array to assign colours to my texts? Please check the code that I have written. The text "hai" is supposed to be in cyan colour. But the output is not as expected.

```js
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
  <script>
    var colors=['blue','cyan','gold','grey','green'];
  </script>
  <h1 style="color:colors[1]">hai</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first give your desired element an *id* then retrieve it through js and style it:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        var colors = ['blue', 'cyan', 'gold', 'grey', 'green'],
            h      = document.getElementById('heading1');
        h.style.color = colors[1];
      };     
    </script>
    <h1 id="heading1">hai</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you dNitro! It actually works. But I am a little confused by the terms 'document.getElementById('heading') and 'h.style.color= colors[1]'. I am a beginner in javascript. So can you please expand these terms?

Comment: Have a look at this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById, It accidentaly also has an example of changing colors.

Answer (score 1):

dNitro's solution works. I'm confused why you need to store colors in an array. If you want to provide different colors to different text. The common solution is design different color styles in css and use it in your element. As the code below

```
  <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <style media="screen">
      .cyan
      {
        color: cyan;
      }
      .blue
      {
        color: blue;
      }
    </style>
    <body>    
      <h1 class="cyan">Hello, </h1>
      <h1 class="blue">World</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you Allen4Tech. Yeah! I am familiar with the standard practice of assigning colors that you have mentioned. I am just trying to figure out a way to loop around  certain colors and produce texts of them. :-)